# Removing the whole word from textarea while pressing backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the whole word while pressing backspace in a text area,while pressing backspace it should check the current word along with one more word contains @, if this matching found while removing it should remove the word else it should remove the letters like what default backspace does.

In my example while removing the text using backspace it should remove the words user and @test in a single key press

Here is my example:

```
 <textarea id="editabletxt">Hello @test user how are you</textarea>

 $('#editabletxt').keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).val().split(' ');
    text.splice(text.length-1); 
    $(this).val(text.join(' '));
  }
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7ZWc/

Comment: `should check the current along with one more word contains @`: can you explain this part please? Can you give some example matches and what it should do in each scenario?

Comment: This is more complicated than it looks like. You need to take the current cursor position into account - otherwise, the current code deletes the last word in the line no matter where the user is editing.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Backspace. Oh my gosh, the functionality you are trying to create already exists!

Comment: @Niet: the functionality might exist, but this is the first time I've heard of it. Live and learn, I guess.

Comment: for example "@test user", here if i press backspace key it should remove the word user as well as the word @test

Comment: It's easy for a human to see that '@test user' should be deleted. However, unless you can always count on user names to ALWAYS have two words, how are you going to be able to determine if the 2nd word is part of the name or not? E.g. "Hi I am @john smith and I am awesome." - how does your program know to delete '@john smith' and not '@john smith and' or just '@john'. Based on what is shown here, there is not enough information to determine that.

Comment: @user3791078 The best answer is going to be someone telling you "DON'T DO THIS". Don't reinvent the wheel. Especially when you're making a change to something so basic. This is the equivalent of changing the space button to insert tabs.

Answer (score 3):

We needed a similar functionality and came up with the following solution,

```js
$.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
    var el = $(this).get(0);
    var pos = 0;
    var posEnd = 0;
    if('selectionStart' in el) {
        pos = el.selectionStart;
        posEnd = el.selectionEnd;
    } else if('selection' in document) {
        el.focus();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
        var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
        Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
        pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        posEnd = Sel.text.length;
    }
    return [pos, posEnd];
};

$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(start, end) {
  $(this).prop("selectionStart", start);
    $(this).prop("selectionEnd", end);
}

$('#text').keydown(function (e) {
    var position = $(this).getCursorPosition();
    var deleted = '';
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (e.which != 8) {
  return true;
    }

    if (position[0] != position[1]) {
  return true;
    }

    if (position[0] <= 0) {
  return true;
    }

    let charToDelete = val.substr(position[0] - 1, 1);
    if ( charToDelete == " " ) {
  return true;
    }

    let nextChar = val.substr(position[0], 1);

    if ( nextChar == " " || nextChar == "" ) {
        start = position[0];
        end = position[0];

        while(val.substr(start - 1, 1) != " " && start - 1 >= 0) {
            start -= 1; 
        }

        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).setCursorPosition(start, end);
        //let newString = val.slice(0, start) + val.slice(end, val.length);
        //$(this).val(newString);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text">Hello @test user how are you</textarea><br />
```

Comment: How would you do this thing if instead of searching for spaces it searches for parenthesis. eg. (Hello[5]). If I move my cursor to end of o then it shoud remove the Hello word only. So the remaining text would be ([5]